# Rephrasing with modal verb

Tags: grammar

How should I rephrase the sentence:

> English cooking isn’t necessarily bad.

using a modal verb?
Is any of the following correct?

> a) English cooking might not be bad.
>
> b) English cooking doesn't need to be bad.
>
> c) English cooking doesn't have to be bad.
>
> d) English cooking need not be bad.

Comment: Shall we vote?  I like c) best.  b) and d) are okay -- they express the same thought.  There is something wrong with a) -- it's hard to interpret as a generalization -- but I can't figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: English cooking *must* not be bad?

Comment: @Greg Lee: What I think goes wrong with (a) is that it sounds like you're not sure whether (1) all English cooking is bad or (2) no English cooking is bad. I don't know why *might not* does that, though.

Comment: If they're asking for real modal verbs, then (1) is the only one. (2) uses the semimodal _need_ as a main verb (a non-modal use of a semimodal). (3) uses a modal paraphrase (_have to_) as a main verb. (4) is a modal use of the semimodal _need_. But (1) is the true, the blushful modal auxiliary verb, with no semi-s and no periphrasis. As for why (1) feels wrong, I think that `Not Necessary` isn't always identical to `Possible Not`, de Morgan to the contrary; in this case I suspect a Gricean idiom.

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite it with a modal verb? I guess what you want to say is that although many people think English cuisine is bad, it is not always so. I would use (AmE) either your original sentence or c), stressing the verb: "English cooking doesn't *have* to be bad"

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler said, B C and D, though grammatical, are not modal (auxiliary) verbs. A fulfils the requirements, though it sounds to me closer in meaning to 'I don't know whether English cooking is bad' than what I presume to be intended, 'English cooking is sometimes good.' The latter would be better expressed 'English cooking may not be bad'.

And you should consider also that to really sound like a native speaker, you should replace 'English' with 'Spanish'.